# JSON data into table needs tr elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to put JSON data into table but can't create tr item for each loop.

I have to have 2 coloumns, Description and Photo itself, only.

**http://jsfiddle.net/28hEb/27/**

```
var userid = "998875@N22";
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=" + userid + "&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.items, function (index, item) {
        $("<td>").html(item.title).appendTo("#table1");
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#table1");
        if (index == 1) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test the next code...

```
var userid = "998875@N22";
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=" + userid + "&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function (data) {

        $.each(data.items, function (index, item) {

            var tr = $('<tr/>');
            var td = $('<td/>').text(item.title);
            var td2 = $('<td/>');
            var img = $('<img/>').attr("src", item.media.m);


            $('#table1').append(tr.append(td, td2.append(img)));

        });
    });
```